# regex to find excel like "formulas"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build regexes that I will use on javascript to analyze strings with excel like formulas
I want only the word that is before parenthesis,

> IF some stuff THEN **FORMULA1**(FORMULA2( this one is not, no words before-> (a+b))) ELSE 'this one(I dont want)'

1:I managed to do this: (\s\S+?(?=()) which gives me FORMULA1 and one(, but I would like it to stop after the first find (ideally I'd like the regex not to include the space before, but I can live with that)

2:because once I find it, I cut the string and re run the find FORMULA2. however my regex doesn't work as there's no white space before FORMULA2 but a ( I need to have something like \s|( but that does not work at all...

3: I want to exclude parenthesis that are between quotes ' I'm at a loss on how to do that

guidance very appreciated !
[here's a regex101 to help](https://regex101.com/r/7HSwiS/1)

Comment: Perhaps like this with a capturing group `'[^']*'|([^\s(]+(?=\())`  https://regex101.com/r/05OF7i/1

Comment: You cannot. Excel-like formulas do not form a regular language.

Comment: Your question is vague. It needs to be complete and unambiguous. You need something like the following, "Given a string I wish to return the first word that is followed by a left parenthesis", or "...by a left parenthesis followed by one or more digits", or "...by a left parenthesis followed by one or more digits followed by one of the characters in the string `"+-*/ "` or something similar. You may be thinking that I am asking too much. I am thinking that this question is asking too much.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you, almost works, but it doesnt ignore the one that is in between quotes, it takes the whole string between quotes.

Comment: @Eagle1 It matches what you don't want (which is from an opening till closing single quote( and what you do want is in the capturing group (what is highlighted in green in the regex101 liink)

Comment: oh yes I'm sorry !  I tried it in jsfiddle and it gives an array with the two formulas ! thank you very much, you should post an answer

Comment: @Eagle1 I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example data, you could use:

```
'[^']*'|([^\s(]+(?=\())
```

**Explanation**

- `'[^']*'` Match from `'` till `'`
- `|` Or
- `(` capture **group 1**
  `- [^\s(]+` Match 1+ times any char other then a whitespace char or `(`

  - `(?=\()` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is `(`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/05OF7i/1)

For example

```js
const regex = /'[^']*'|([^\s(]+(?=\())/g;
const str = `IF some stuff THEN FORMULA1(FORMULA2(that it is but not this one (a+b))) ELSE 'this one(I dont want)'`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (undefined !== m[1]) console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: when I .match() this regex in JS (with the gm flag), I get an array of all the results, including the ones "I dont wany". How can I make the difference in js ? (appart from checking if there are ' in the string) https://jsfiddle.net/Morgorth/d9hf08wc/

Comment: @Eagle1 You could take the group 1 value. I have added an example in Javascript.